# How to pass arguments to YUI3's 'on' method callbacks?

Tags: javascript, yui, yui3

I have 2 event handlers:

```
Y.all(".ptl").on("mouseover", handleOverlay); 
Y.all(".ptl").on("mouseout", handleOverlay);
```

And I would like to pass an arugment to `handleOverlay` on mouseout so that the function knows that the user has exited the node and to exit the `handleOverlay` function.

I have attemped to follow the API http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/YUI.html#method_on which to me indicates that it should be:

```
Y.all(".ptl").on("mouseout", handleOverlay, null, null, null, {arg: "myarg});
```

however in `handleOverlay`, assuming that the first argument is the node, the second argument is undefined, prior to the on method, and then null after instead of containing the object passed to it.

`function handleOverlay(node, te) {}`

node = node object in question (as expected)

te = undefined prior to the mouseover, and null after the mouseout.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function mousedOver(e, arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    //blah blah blah arg1 arg2 arg3
}   

Y.all("#target").on("mouseover", mousedOver, null, "foo", "bar", "baz");
```

You can pass whatever you want in as those custom arguments. Objects, strings, function references... go nuts!

Comment: Thanks a ton, I must have been mis-reading the API thinking that only the 6th spot was for the arguments.